# How do I find the proper transfer function of this passive filter?

Tags: control, transfer-function

I've been looking at this circuit for a long time trying to derive the transfer function of it.

[image]

My attempt goes like so.

You can separate the circuit into two RC filters, into a system that looks like this:

[image]
where each block is like so:

[image]

We can then simplify H1(s) by combining impedences:

[image]

Where Z = R||C or R in parallel with C
This is the same as $$\frac{1}{\frac{1}{R}+SC} = \frac{R}{RCS+1}$$

This is where I get stuck, there's no voltage divider, so I cannot use a regular transfer function like one would use for an RC circuit.

The answer, however, is known:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my approach? would a more formal KVL/KCL approach be required? what would the correct approach look like?

Comment: Hint: if the input source is an ideal voltage source, two of the components have no effect on the transfer function.

Comment: You should edit your diagrams to show an "\$I_{in}\$" instead of \$v_{in}\$ to make that more clear.

Comment: @ThePhoton done. My bad

Comment: You can't separate the circuits as stated - e.g. the third RC loads the second, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to solve this transfer function and organize it in a normalized form. The first approach is the brute-force algebra: identify a Thévenin generator with the parallel combination of \$C_1\$ and \$R_1\$ followed by an equivalent \$R_{th}\$ of the same value. Then you combine the other impedances as voltage dividers accounting for the previous equivalent resistances:

[image]

Good luck in expanding this ugly expression and even more luck in organizing it in a canonical form. The situation may be different if you adopt the fast analytical circuits techniques or [FACTs](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1119236371). You start by setting \$s=0\$ and redraw the circuit with open-circuited capacitors. The transimpedance value in this case is simply the first resistance \$R_1\$. Then, "look" at the resistance offered by each capacitor to form a time constant associated with each capacitor. Adding all these time constants leads to determining term \$b_1\$ in the denominator. Now, place \$C_1\$ in its high-frequency state (a short circuit) and "look" at the resistance offered by \$C_2\$ and \$C_3\$. Proceed and determine \$b_2\$ by multiplying time constants. Then, for \$b_3\$, place \$C_2\$ and \$C_1\$ in their high-frequency state and "look" at the resistance from \$C_3\$'s connecting terminals in this mode: you have \$b_3\$ by combining this last result with the two previously-determined time constants. The below drawing shows how to get there:

[image]

You can now express the denominator by \$D(s)=1+sb_1+s^2b_2+s^3b_3\$ and the transfer function is then defined as: \$\frac{V_{out}(s)}{I_{in}(s)}=R_1\frac{1}{D(s)}\$. The below Mathcad sheet shows how to get there:

[image]

If you now reduce this expression by having only \$R\$ and \$C\$, you find:

[image]

which is the expression you want. It can probably be rearranged in a better way by combining a second-order polynomial form and a 1st-order pole but it is time for a glass of wine :-)

Answer (score 2):

First of all: use [reference designators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator), it makes addressing components way easier!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fldkIl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As Chu comments, you cannot separate the circuits as you did with the red boxes. E.g. the impedance right of R2 is not only determined by C2, but by C2||(R3+C3).

**How to solve the circuit?**
Formal KVL/KCL approach would work, using voltage divider and/or parallel impedances may also work.
Regarding the latter: you can combine starting from the **right** side, combining impedences Za = (R3+C3)||C2, working your way back to the left (so, next is Zb = (Za+R2)||C1||R1) and then determine the voltage across R1 and C1 using Iin.
Next, you can use voltage dividing working your way from left to right again (first using Zb and Za, then expanding their terms).

**When would it allowed to split the transfer function into blocks?**
If the circuit were as follows (with ideal unity gain amplifiers) it would be allowed to split the transfer function in blocks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCN4ro.png)</sup>

Comment: All R and C are equal.  Designators are not needed

Comment: It is needed to explain which C your are paralleling with which R, but you're right that for the answer it will not matter.

Comment: ah. Makes more sense